# comparing the value of data extracated from database and label data in repeater does not work asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

i want to make the edit button visible for only those users who has the same user id as the data extracted from database. for this I'm using repeater and I'v extracted data using repeater but when i compare the user log in value and data from database inside repeater,i don't get the value inside button.can anyone help please. here's my code;

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="delete" 
  CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id") %>' 
  OnClick="lbtnDelete_Click" Visible='<%# lLoggedUser.Text == DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "user_id") %>'>Edit</asp:LinkButton>
```

here lLoggedUser is login user id and "user_id" is id of user in database.
But the value of lUserLogged get null.

Answer (score 0):

Compare it to the data you bind to `LoggedUser`, not the value of `LoggedUser` itself. Like

```
Visible='<%# Eval("user_id").ToString() == Session["user_id"].ToString() %>
```

or

```
Visible='<%# Eval("user_id") == MyUserIDVariable %>
```

Comment: Thank you VDWWD. But I tried like i stored a value from session and set in a label named lLoggedUser so I compared to lLoggedUser. But when i directly try to compare with the variable storing session value, it can't be called from .aspx, I did same way in gridview it worked fine but this time in repeater it's not working.